# How to get member of details recently created ad users via powershell in html

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to fetch ad user created details, but unable to get member of details, below is my script

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |where { $_.whenCreated -ge $date } | 
select Name, 
MemberOf, 
whenCreated,
DisplayName,
Surname,
EmployeeID,
mail| ConvertTo-Html | Out-File d:\test.html

Invoke-item d:\test.html
```

In HTML it is giving below output for memberof column-
" Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is a multivalued attribute try the following

```
date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |where { $_.whenCreated -ge $date } | 
select Name, 
@{name=”MemberOf”;expression={$_.memberof -join “;”}}, 
whenCreated,
DisplayName,
Surname,
EmployeeID,
mail| ConvertTo-Html | Out-File D:\test.html
```

Comment: Hi @drifter104 can i det only the group name instead of complete CN